# Install package in quasar with webpack

Tags: webpack, quasar-framework

I need to install the next pack in to quasar 1.22:

https://github.com/kbumsik/opus-media-recorder/tree/master

I have follow the sample used as webpack in

https://github.com/kbumsik/opus-media-recorder/blob/master/example/webpack/webpack.config.js

I tried the next in quasar.conf, but I get an error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* a in ./node_modules/opus-media-recorder/WebMOpusEncoder.wasm, ./node_modules/opus-media-recorder/OggOpusEncoder.wasm



extendWebpack(cfg) {
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            devtool: 'source-map',
            preventExtract: true,
          },
        })
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          test: /node_modules\/opus-media-recorder\/encoderWorker\.js$/,
          loader: 'worker-loader',
        })
        cfg.module.rules.push({
          test: /node_modules\/opus-media-recorder\/.*\.wasm$/,
          type: 'javascript/auto',
          loader: 'file-loader',
        })

        cfg.devtool = 'source-map'
      },
```